# SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager is deprecated

Tags: java

I am writing SVN code, this method is deprecated, but i see the api document, no recommand to me , is any better api to use ?

SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager is deprecated

Comment: also SVNURL.parseURIDecoded is depracated....

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I looked at the source code of the project and I found that there is another method that accepts a password as a char[].

Then you can use:

```
 authMgr = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password.toCharArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just to change the second parameter from String to Char[]